# Can anyone provide the Kafka Sink Connector example Java?

Tags: apache-flink

To be honest, I am at a very primary level of using Apache Flink, I am looking for the Apache Flink sink connector which will send my messages to Kafka topic.

Looking forward to quick help.

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html

Comment: @chesnay Schepler, Yes, I am struggling to get something called **JSONKeySerializationSchema**

In the consumption (**De**-Serialization) side I did as below and it's working perfectly. 

FlinkKafkaConsumer010<ObjectNode> consumer10 = new FlinkKafkaConsumer010<ObjectNode>(
    KAFKA_CONSUMER_TOPIC_NAME,
    new JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema(false), properties);

Answer (score 1):

The Apache Flink training has [an exercise on the topic of writing to and reading from Kafka](http://dataartisans.github.io/flink-training/exercises/toFromKafka.html). Included are reference solutions which you can use as a guide. The link I've given you is a deep link to the relevant exercise -- you'll probably want to browse around and explore more of the material there as well.

Comment: Thanks.! I will deep dive and check it. As I have gone through quickly, I am looking something like TaxiRideSchema.java, But there is a problem I could see it's not helping to serialize **key** for Kafka message, its serializing **message** part.

Comment: Thanks, I have embedded **key** part into a message body part and I am able to write messages into Kafka topic using Flink sink connector.